# Loading xml content with ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

Ok so i have the following html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th,
  td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get the names</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table id="demo"></table>

  <script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          myFunction(xhttp);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "names.xml", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(xml) {
      var i;
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      var table = "<tr><th>Names</th></tr>";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Names");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +
          x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And the following xml file containing names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Names>
  <Name>Alex</Name>
  <Name>Anna</Name>
  <Name>Eva</Name>
  <Name>George</Name>
  <Name>Jason</Name>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Name>Lisa</Name>
  <Name>Mary</Name>
  <Name>Michael</Name>
  <Name>Nick</Name>
  <Name>Vicky</Name>
</Names>
```

And what i want is to somehow take the names from the xml file and store them inside an array and then print them.But for some reason only the first name is stored correctly("Alex").I dont understand what i have done wrong.Can somebody help me? I bet there is something wrong with the `myFunction(xml)` but i cant find/fix it

Comment: Use the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Are there any errors? What if you add `console.log` statements? Does `loadDoc` run at all? Does `myFunction` run at all? Is the value of `xml` what you expect? Is the value of `x` what you expect? Is the value of `x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue` what you expect?

Comment: yes i have tried but came up empty...

Comment: What does that mean? Do you mean there were no errors and one of the values you tested for a zero length string?

Comment: yes no errors... i need help with this

Comment: OK, so there weren't any errors. What did you get when you added `console.log` statements at *all* of the points I suggested adding them at?

Comment: where did you suggested i add the console.log?I am new to js and ajax so a little more help would be good

Comment: Look at my first comment. All but the first two sentences are suggestions of where to put console.log statements.

Comment: sorry for this but can you show me where exactly in my code i must add the console.log???

Comment: If you want to check if a function is being run, log immediately at the top of the function. If you want to check a variable, check immediately before you use that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check this:

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Names"); // Get the Names node.
var data = x[0].getElementsByTagName("Name"); // Get the Name node.
```

```js
(function() {

  function myFunction(xml) {
    var i;
    var xmlDoc = (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
    var table = "<tr><th>Names</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Names");

    var data = x[0].getElementsByTagName("Name");

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      table += "<tr><td>" + data[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
  }

  var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><Names>  <Name>Alex</Name>  <Name>Anna</Name>  <Name>Eva</Name>  <Name>George</Name>  <Name>Jason</Name>  <Name>John</Name>  <Name>Lisa</Name>  <Name>Mary</Name>  <Name>Michael</Name>  <Name>Nick</Name>  <Name>Vicky</Name></Names>";
  myFunction(xml);


})();
```

```html
<table id="demo"></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is only one `Names` tag so your loop will only execute once.
I would loop over the `Name` tags instead.

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table = "<tr><th>Names</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Name");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
      x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```